# How to SUM the values from group in SSRS which are distinct

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report where I want to calculate the Grand total but ignore the values of a group which have same value. Below are my tables and the data. The Package No column is grouped and will be unique always, but every unique Package may or may not have same dimensions. I want to SUM the dimension (Length, Width and Height) and it Package No has multiple items in it then have to consider only the first row for summing up the values as the dimensions will remain the same for all the items within the same Package. Can anyone please help me to achieve this result?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the data that gets returned from your dataset query looks like the sample you show in the image then you should be able to do something like...

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!RowNum.Value = 1, Fields!Length.Value, 0))
```

---

**EDIT after OP update**

If the RowNum column is not in your dataset then you will need to add it.

If you dataset query is just a script then it should be as easy as something like this...

```
SELECT *
    , RownN =  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PackageNo ORDER BY Item)
 FROM myTable
```

If the dataset is the result of a stored proc then you might have to change the dataset query to something like

```
CREATE TABLE #t (PackageNo varchar(50), Length int, Width int, Height int, Item varchar(50))

INSERT INTO #t 
    EXEC myStoredProc

    SELECT *
        , RownN =  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PackageNo ORDER BY Item)
     FROM #t
```

Once one of the above options are been taken then you should be able to simply apply the `=SUM(IIF(Fields!RowN.Value = 1, Fields!Length.Value, 0))`
 expression in your report totals.

Comment: The Row Number is not coming from query, I have added a new column and in that added a expression to display RowNumber per group like RowNumber("PackageNo"). So the expression mentioned by you is not working. I want to this at report level only.

Comment: Thank you so much, I applied the above logic and it worked.